# dirtree compilation issue (extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr)

Tags: subfloats, forest

I have got a forest in two subfloats as bellow:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax

% Package to generate and customize Algorithm as per ACM style
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}
\include{definitions}

% DOI
\doi{0000001.0000001}

%ISSN
\issn{1234-56789}

% Document starts
\begin{document}


\forestset{
  dir tree/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south west,
      child anchor=west,
      anchor=mid west,
      inner ysep=-3pt,
      grow'=0,
      align=left,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      %font=\sffamily,
      if n children=0{}{
        delay={
          prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
        }
      },
      fit=rectangle,
      before computing xy={
        l=2em
      }
    },
  }
}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\subfloat{
\label{fig:contribution_left}
\begin{forest}
  dir tree
  [\textbf{Paper Organization} 
    [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:promises and challenges} Promises and challenges}
        [optimization benefits]
        [Optimization space
            [The selection]
            [The phase-ordering]    
        ]    
    ]    
    [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:characterization techniques} Characterization}
      [Hybrid]
      [Dimension Reduction Techniques
        [Principal Component Analysis]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}}

\subfloat{
\label{fig:contribution_right}
\begin{forest}
  dir tree
  [
   [\textbf{\pmb{\S}  \ref{sec:predication_classes}  Prediction Classifications}
      [Feature predictors]
   ]
   [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:DSE} Design Space Exploration}            
        [Compilation]   
   ]
   [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:Target Domain} Target Domain}
      [Target architecture
          [Embedded systems]
          [Workstations & HPC domain]
      ]
      [Target Compiler 
          [GCC]
      ] 
    ] 
     [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:Evaluations} Evaluations}
        [Performance comparisons]     
     ]
    % [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:conclusion} Conclusion and future challenges}]
  ]
\end{forest}}
\caption{Organization of the paper in different sections}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where did I miss a tab, extra column, etc that I am getting this error:

```
extra alignment tab has been changed to cr
```

Comment: Please post complete code we can (try to!) compile!

Comment: done @cfr. Sorry

Comment: @amir That's not complete code; it's still a fragment. Complete code includes `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin/end{document}`.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I don't think that was necessary. Anyways, please look at the updated question.

Comment: Do note that code should be attributed to ... er ... whoever wrote it ;).

Comment: That is not very minimal. A minimal example should contain just enough code to demonstrate the problem. Here, only the second tree is needed and most of the preamble can be  cut.

Comment: The original one is much bigger, so I cut it in halves using two subfloats. I still have to find a way to break using its built-in methods to two left and right trees. So can I ask what the problem was ?

Comment: You should ping somebody if you want them to know you asked something, unless there's only one user involved in the discussion. Please see my answer for an explanation of the problem. I don't understand what you mean about the built-in methods etc., but presumably you do so that's OK!

Comment: Note that you should not give `h` as the sole specifier to a float ever. It means 'put it here, if there's room'. What if there isn't room? Then there is nowhere to put it at all!

Comment: Are you really trying to split the tree into two columns? If so, see my edit below (also for a simpler, updated definition of `dir tree`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampersands must be preceded by backslashes outside `array`, `tabular` etc. environments and within those environments if an ampersand should be typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\forestset{
  dir tree/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south west,
      child anchor=west,
      anchor=mid west,
      inner ysep=-3pt,
      grow'=0,
      align=left,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      %font=\sffamily,
      if n children=0{}{
        delay={
          prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
        }
      },
      fit=rectangle,
      before computing xy={
        l=2em
      }
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\subfloat{%
% \label{fig:contribution_left}% no point in using a label here
\begin{forest}
  dir tree
  [\textbf{Paper Organization}
    [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:promises and challenges} Promises and challenges}
        [optimization benefits]
        [Optimization space
            [The selection]
            [The phase-ordering]
        ]
    ]
    [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:characterization techniques} Characterization}
      [Hybrid]
      [Dimension Reduction Techniques
        [Principal Component Analysis]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
}

\subfloat{%
\begin{forest}
  dir tree
  [
   [\textbf{\pmb{\S}  \ref{sec:predication_classes}  Prediction Classifications}
      [Feature predictors]
   ]
   [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:DSE} Design Space Exploration}
        [Compilation]
   ]
   [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:Target Domain} Target Domain}
      [Target architecture
          [Embedded systems]
          [Workstations \& HPC domain]
      ]
      [Target Compiler
          [GCC]
      ]
    ]
     [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:Evaluations} Evaluations}
        [Performance comparisons]
     ]
%     % [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:conclusion} Conclusion and future challenges}]
  ]
\end{forest}
}
\caption{Organization of the paper in different sections}\label{fig:contributions}% label needs to follow caption
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: directory contents listing]

Note that current Forest provides built-in methods for drawing this type of tree and `dir tree` is no longer necessary or may be significantly simplified.

The following example updates `dir tree` to a very simple definition using the new library and demonstrates how to split the tree into two columns, since I gather that maybe what you are really trying to do with the sub-floats.

Rather than splitting the tree, we simply move part of it to another position and alter the `edge path` where necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\forestset{%
  dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      grow'=0,
      s sep'-=5pt,
    },
    where={level()<2}{font=\bfseries}{},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}% never use h as the sole specifier
\centering
\begin{forest}
  dir tree
  [Paper Organization
    [\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:promises and challenges} Promises and challenges
        [optimization benefits]
        [Optimization space
            [The selection]
            [The phase-ordering]
        ]
    ]
    [\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:characterization techniques} Characterization
      [Hybrid]
      [Dimension Reduction Techniques
        [Principal Component Analysis]
      ]
    ]
    [\pmb{\S}  \ref{sec:predication_classes}  Prediction Classifications,
      before drawing tree={%
        tempdima/.max={(x)+(max_x)}{r,tree},
        tempdimb={y("!r1")-y()},
        for current and following nodes={%
          x+/.register=tempdima,
          y+/.register=tempdimb,
        },
        for current and following siblings={%
          edge path'={%
            (!r.parent anchor) +({\forestregister{tempdima}+\forestregister{folder indent}},0) |- (.child anchor)
          },
        },
      }
      [Feature predictors]
    ]
    [\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:DSE} Design Space Exploration
        [Compilation]
    ]
    [\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:Target Domain} Target Domain
      [Target architecture
          [Embedded systems]
          [Workstations \& HPC domain]
      ]
      [Target Compiler
          [GCC]
      ]
    ]
    [\textbf{\pmb{\S} \ref{sec:Evaluations} Evaluations}
        [Performance comparisons]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\caption{Organization of the paper in different sections}\label{fig:contributions}% label needs to follow caption
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: split tree]