# Forest - TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000]

Tags: forest, capacity

I am a novice when it comes to anything related to Latex, so I am sorry if I am unclear or dense.

I am using the latest Trisquel operating system. I am trying to make a large tree with Forest from the latest update of TexLive and keep getting the error TeX capacity exceeded. When I chop the tree up into smaller parts, I get the trees I want, but I would like compile this into one large tree. I have tried using Lualatex and increasing the main_memory, but with no success. I was hoping someone might have a solution or see something wrong with my original Tex file. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Here is the error:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].
>   \pgfmath@stack@push ...def \pgfmath@stack@top {#2}
>                                                     \expandafter \expandafter ...
>   l.908 \end{forest}
>   !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Here is the file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=0,anchor=base west},
  forked edges,
  [Amerind
[Chibchan-Paezan
  [Chibchan
    [Tarascan]
    [Cuitlatec]
    [Xinca]
    [Lenca]
    [Paya]
    [Yanomam
      [Sanuma]
      [Yanomami]
      [Yanomam\"{o} (Yanomamo)]
      [Ninam]
    ]
    [Nuclear Chibchan
      [Motilon]
      [Cuna]
      [Misumalpan
        [Matagalpa]
        [Miskito]
        [Sumo]
      ]
      [Rama
        [Rama]
        [Guatuso]
        [Guetar (Huetar)]
      ]  
      [Talamanca
        [Cabecar]
        [Bribri]
        [Teribe]
        [Borunca]
      ]
      [Guaymi
        [Guaymi (Ngobe)]
        [Buglere]
      ]
      [Antioquia
        [Katio] 
        [Nutabe]
        [Anserma]
        [Arma]
      ]
      [Aruak
        [Atanque]
        [Guamaca]
        [Ica (Ijka)]
        [Cagaba (Kogi)]
        [Chimila]
        [Malayo (Arsario)]
      ]
      [Chibchan Proper
        [Chibcha] 
        [Sinsiga] 
        [Duit] 
        [Tunebo
         [Eastern Tunebo
          [Central Tunebo]
          [Western Tunebo]
  ] ] ] ] ]
  [Paezan
    [Timucua]
    [Warao]
    [Kunza (Atacameno)]
    [Betoi]
    [Chimu]
    [Itonama]
    [Haurpe
      [Allentiac]
      [Millcayac]
    ]
    [Jirajaran
      [Ayoman]
      [Gayon]
      [Jirajara]
    ]
    [Mura
      [Mura]
      [Matanawi]
    ]
    [Nuclear Paezan
      [Andaqui]
      [Choco
        [Embera (Embera)] 
        [Saija] 
        [Catio] 
        [Caramanta]
        [Chami] 
        [Tado] 
        [Baudo]
        [Waunana (Wounan)]
        [Runa]
      ]
      [Inter-Andine
        [Coconucan
          [Guambiano]
          [Coconuco]
          [Totono]
        ]
        [Paez
          [Paez]
        ]
        [Popayan
          [Popayan]
      ] ]
      [Barbacoan
        [Pasto
          [Cuaiquer]
          [Barbacoas]
        ]
        [Cayapa-Colorado
          [Cayapa (Cayapa)]
          [Colorado]
] ] ] ] ]
[Ge-Pano-Carib
  [Macro-Carib
    [Andoke]
    [Cucura]
    [Peba-Yaguan
      [Peba]
      [Yameo]
      [Yagua]
    ]
    [Bora-Witoto
      [Baran
        [Bora]
        [Faai]
        [Imihita]
        [Muinane]
      ]
      [Witotoan
        [Fitita]
        [Ocaina]
        [Nonuya]
        [Orejone]
        [Coeruna]
        [Witoto Proper
          [Meneca]
          [Murui]
    ] ] ]
    [Carib
      [Northern
        [Costal
          [Venezuelan
            [Chayma] 
            [Cumanagoto]
            [Yao] 
            [Tamanaco]
          ]
          [Sierra De Perija
            [Japreria]
            [Yukpa]
          ]
          [Opone-Carare
            [Opone]
            [Carare]
        ] ]
        [Western Guiana
          [Mapoyo] 
          [Yabarana]
          [Panare] 
          [Quaca] 
          [Pareca]
        ]
        [Galibi
          [Galibi (Kal'ina)]
        ]
        [East-West Guiana
          [Group 1
            [Wayana]
            [Apalai (Apalai)]
            [Roucouyene]
            [Aracaju]
            [Trio]
          ]
          [Group 2
            [Wama]
            [Urukuyana]
            [Triometesen]
            [Kumayena]
          ]
          [Group 3
            [Pianakoto]
            [Saluma] 
            [Paushi] 
            [Cashuena]
            [Chilhena]
            [Wai Wai (Wai Wai)]
          ]
          [Group 4
            [Paravilhana]
            [Wabui]
            [Sapara]
            [Yauapery]
            [Waimiri]
            [Crianara]
            [Paushiana]
            [Bonari]
          ]
          [Group 5
            [Makushi (Macushi)]
            [Pemon] 
            [Patamona]
            [Akawaio]
            [Arinagoto]
        ] ]
        [Northern Brazil
          [Group 1
            [Palmella]
            [Pimenteira]
          ]
          [Group 2
            [Yaruma]
            [Chic\^{a}o]
          ]
          [Group 3
            [Pariri]
            [Apiaka]
            [Arara (Arara)]
            [Yuma]
      ] ] ]
      [Southern
        [Southeastern Columbia
          [Hianacoto] 
          [Guaque] 
          [Carijona]
        ]
        [Xingu Basin
          [Bakairi] 
          [Nanukwa]
        ]
        [Southern Guiana
          [Ye'Cuana (Yekuana?)]
          [Wayumara] 
          [Parukoto] 
          [Hishkaryana]
          [Kashuyana]
  ] ] ] ]
  [Ge-Pano
    [Macro-Panoan
      [Charruan
        [Charrua]
        [Chana] 
        [G\"{u}enoa]
      ]
      [Lulu-Vilela
        [Lule] 
        [Vilela]
      ]
      [Mascoian
        [Guana]
        [Northern Lengua] 
        [Southern Lengua] 
        [Emok]
      ] 
      [Moseten
        [Chimane (Chimane; Moseten)]
      ] 
      [Mataco-Guaicuru
        [Guaicuruan
          [Abipon] 
          [Kadiweu]
          [Guaicuru]
          [Guachi] 
          [Mocovi] 
          [Toba (Toba)]
          [Pilaga (Pilaga)]
        ]
        [Mataco
          [Chulupi]
          [Chorote]
          [Nocten (Wichi?)] 
          [Vejoz] 
          [Maca]
      ] ]
      [Pano-Tacana
        [Panoan
          [Southern
            [Chacobo]
            [Pacahuara]
            [Caripuna]
            [Sinabo] 
            [Surina]
          ]
          [South-Central
            [Amanuaca] 
            [Parquenahua]
            [Yaminahua-Sharanahua
              [Yaminahua] 
              [Poyanawa] 
              [Shipinawa]
              [Tushinawa]
              [Sharanahua]
          ] ]
          [South-Eastern
            [Cashinahua]
            [Morunahua] 
            [Catuquina] 
            [Shahuanahua]
            [Camanahua]
          ]
          [Western
            [Sashibo]
          ]
          [North-Central
            [Capanahua] 
            [Shipibo (Shipibo)] 
            [Isconahua] 
            [Remo] 
            [Marubo]
            [Capuibo]
            [Sensi] 
            [Niarawa]
            [Pichobo]
            [Arawa] 
            [Atsahuaca]
          ]
          [Northern
            [Matses]
            [Mayubo]
            [R\"{e}moybo]
            [Pisabo]
          ]
          [Eastern
            [Kasharari]
        ] ]
        [Tacanan
          [Yamaluba]
          [Arasa]
          [Guariza] 
          [Chirigua
            [Maropa]
            [Chumana]
            [Sapiboca]
          ]
          [Tiatinagua-Tacana
            [Tiatinagua
              [Es\'{e}ejja]
              [Huarayo]
            ]
            [Araona-Tacana
              [Araona
                [Capachena]
                [Mabenaro]
                [Araona]
              ]
              [Cavine\`{n}a-Tacana
                [Cavine\`{n}a
                  [Cavine\`{n}a]
                ]
                [Tacana Proper
                  [Tacana] 
                  [Reyesano]
                  [Toromono]
    ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
    [Macro-Ge
      [Rikbaktsa]
      [Fulnio] 
      [Guato] 
      [Opaye] 
      [Oti] 
      [Caraja]
      [Bororo
        [Bororo Proper
          [Bororo] 
          [Umotina]
          [Aravira]
        ]
        [Otuke
          [Otuke]
          [Covare]
          [Conaveca]
          [Curucane]
          [Tapii]
      ] ]
      [Botocudo
        [Botocudo
      ] ]
      [Chiquito
        [Chiquito]
      ]
      [Kamakan
        [Kutasho]
        [Masacara]
        [Menien] 
        [Mongoyo]
        [Kamakan]
      ]
      [Puri
        [Puri]
        [Coroado]
        [Coropo]
      ]
      [Yabuti
        [Aricapu]
        [Yabuti]
      ]
      [Mashakali
        [Mashakali]
      ]
      [Ge-Kaingang
        [Kaingang
          [Dorin]
          [Northern
            [Kaingang (Kaingang)]
            [Xokleng] 
            [Chiqui]
          ]
          [Southern
            [Amno] 
            [Ingain]
            [Gualachi]
        ] ]
        [Ge
          [Central
            [Acroa
              [Acroa]
              [Aricobe]
              [Guegue]
            ]
            [Aaia?
              [Chavante (Xauante)]
              [Cherente]
          ] ]
          [Northwest
            [Apinaye]
            [Suya]
            [Kreen-Akarore]
            [Cayapo (Gorotire; Kuben Kran Kegn; Mekranoti; Xikrin)]
            [Canela]
] ] ] ] ] ]
[Andean
  [Northern
    [Culli]
    [Sec] 
    [Leco]
    [Catacao
      [Catacao]
      [Colan]
    ]
    [Cholona
      [Cholona]
      [Hibito]
  ] ]
  [Urarina-Waorani
    [Urarina] 
    [Waorani (Waorani)]
    [Omurano]
  ] 
  [Cahuapanan-Zaparoan
    [Cahuapanan
      [Chayahuita (Snawi)]
      [Jebero] ] 
    [Zaparoan
      [Zaparo]
      [Andoa (Andoas)] 
      [Arabela] 
      [Cahuarano]
      [Iquito]
  ] ]
  [Quechuan
    [Quechua A (Huiliche; Arequipa; Cajamarca; Chankas; Chopcca; Karanki; Quechua Bolivia; Quechua Lamistas; Quechua Peru; Quecha Pucachupa; Tayacaja)]
    [Quechua B (Huancas; Kichwa; Yungay)]
  ]
  [Aymaran
    [Aymara (Aymara Bolivia; Aymara Chile; Aymara Peru; Aymara Titicaca)]
    [Jaqaru (Tupe)]
  ]
  [Southern
    [Puelche
      [Puelche (Penuenche)]
    ]
    [Mapudungu
      [Mapudungu (Mapuche)]
      [Huilliche]
    ]
    [Qawasqar-Yamana
      [Qawasqar]
      [Yamana (Yaghan)]
    ]
    [Patagonian
      [Tenuelche? (Tenuenche)] 
      [Teushen] 
      [Selknam] 
      [Haush]
] ] ]
[Equiatorial-Tucanoan
  [Ma\'{c}o-Tucanoan
    [Auishiri]
    [Canichana]
    [Capishana]
    [Gamella]
    [Iranshe]
    [Koaia] 
    [Movima (Movima)]
    [Muniche]
    [Nate] 
    [Pankararu]
    [Shukuru]
    [Uman]
    [Catuquinan
      [Northern
        [Catawishi]
      ]
      [Southern
        [Bendiapa]
        [Burua] 
        [Canamari]
        [Catuquina]
        [Parawa] 
        [Taware] 
        [Tucundiapa]
    ] ]
    [Huari
      [Huari]
      [Masaca]
    ]
    [Arutani-Sape
      [Arutani] 
      [Sape] 
      [Macu]
    ]
    [Nambikuaran
      [Northern Nambikuara]
      [Southern Nambikuara]
      [Sabanes] 
      [Sarare]
    ]
    [Puinave-Maku
      [Puinave] 
      [Maku
        [Hupda]
        [Guariba]
        [Nad\"{e}b] 
        [Yahup] 
        [Cacua]
    ] ]
    [Ticuna-Yuri
      [Ticuna (Ticuna)]
      [Yuri]
    ] 
    [Tucanoan
      [Miriti]
      [Eastern
        [Northern
          [Tucano]
          [Guanano]
          [Piratapuyo]
        ]
        [Central
          [Bara
            [Tuyuca]
          ]
          [Desano
            [Desano]
            [Siriano]
          ]
          [Tatuyo
            [Tatuyo]
            [Carapana]
        ] ]
        [Southern
          [Macuna
            [Macuna]
          ]
          [Barasano
            [Northern Barasona]
            [Southern Barasona]
      ] ] ]
      [Central
        [Cubeo]
      ]
      [Western
        [Tanimuca]
        [Northern
          [Coreguaje]
          [Tetete] 
          [Tama] 
          [Siona-Secoya
            [Siona] 
            [Secoya]
            [Macaguaje]
  ] ] ] ] ]
  [Equatorial
    [Cayuvava]
    [Camsa]
    [Taruma] 
    [Trumai] 
    [Tusha] 
    [Yuracare (Yuracare)] 
    [Piaroa-Saliba
      [Piaroa] 
      [Saliba]
    ]
    [Timote
      [Cuica]
      [Timote]
    ]
    [Jivaroan
      [Cofan]
      [Esmeralda]
      [Yaruro] 
      [Candoshi
        [Candoshi]
        [Taushiro]
      ]
      [Jivaro Proper (Jivaro)
        [Achuar (Achuar)]
        [Shuar]
        [Huambisa (Huambisa)]
        [Aguaruna (Awajun)]
    ] ]
    [Zamucoan
      [Ayoreo (Ayoreo)]
      [Chamacoco]
    ] 
    [Kariri-Tua
      [Kariri
        [Ozubucua]
        [Kamaru] 
        [Kiriri] 
        [Sapuya]
      ]
      [Tupi
        [Purubora]
        [Yuqui] 
        [Arikem
          [Arikem]
          [Kabishiana]
          [Karitiana]
        ]
        [Monde
          [Arua]
          [Gavi\~{a}o (Gavi\~{a}o; Zoro)] 
          [Surui (Surui)] 
          [Monde (Cinta Larga)] 
          [Dig\"{u}t]
        ] 
        [Ramarama
          [Arara]
          [Ramarama]
          [Uruku] 
          [Urumi]
        ]
        [Yuruna
          [Yuruna]
          [Manitsawa]
          [Shipaya]
        ]
        [Tupari
          [Guarategaya]
          [Kepkiriwat]
          [Makurapi] 
          [Tupari] 
          [Wayoro]
        ]
        [Tupi-Guarani
          [Guayaki (Ache)]
          [Juma] 
          [Group 1
            [Apiaca]
            [Aweti]
            [Aua] 
            [Kamayura]
            [Kayabi]
            [Emerillion (Emerillion)]
            [Karipura] 
            [Oyampi (Wayampi)]
            [Pauserna] 
            [Sheta] 
            [Takunape]
            [Tapirape]
            [Kawahiba
              [Paranawat]
              [Tenharim]
              [Takunape]
              [Werafed]
            ]
            [Tenetehana
              [Amanaye]
              [Anambe] 
              [Tembe] 
              [Guajajana]
              [Guaja] 
              [Asurini]
              [Arawete]
              [Paraka\~{n}a (Parakana)]
              [Urubu]
            ]
            [Tupi
              [Guarani (Guarani)]
              [Kaiwa] 
              [Tapiete]
              [Guarayu]
              [Nhengatu]
              [Potiguara]
          ] ]
          [Group 2
            [Cocama]
            [Omagua]
          ]
          [Group 3
            [Mawe]
            [Munduruku (Munduruku)] 
            [Siriono] 
            [Kuruaya]
    ] ] ] ]
    [Macro-Arawakan
      [Katembri]
      [Oromaco] 
      [Tiniguan
        [Tinigua]
        [Pamigua]
      ]
      [Guahiban
        [Churuya]
        [Guahibo (Guahibo)]
        [Cuiba] 
        [Guayabero]
        [Macaguan]
        [Playero]
      ]
      [Arawakan
        [Guamo]
        [Taino]
        [Chamicuro]
        [Arawan
          [Arawa]
          [Culina]
          [Pama] 
          [Paumari]
          [Sewacu]
          [Sipo] 
          [Deni] 
          [Yamamadi (Jamamadi)]
          [Yuberi] 
          [Banawa]
        ]
        [Chipayan
          [Chipaya (Uros Chipaya)]
          [Uru (Los Uros; Uros)] 
          [Cauahuaya] 
          [Caranga] ] 
        [Chapacuran
          [Guapore
            [Chapacura
              [Chapacura]
              [Itene] 
              [Quitemoca]
            ]
            [Wanyam
              [Cabishi]
              [Cujuna]
              [Cumana]
              [Matawa]
              [Wanyam]
              [Urunamacan]
          ] ]
          [Madeina
            [Pakaasnovos]
            [Tora] 
            [Urupa]
          ]
          [Ocorono
            [Herisobocono]
            [Ocorono] 
            [San Ignacio]
        ] ]
        [Maipuran
          [Shebayo]
          [Baniva-Yavitero
            [Baniva] 
            [Yavitero] ]
          [Paressi-Saraveca
            [Paressi] 
            [Saraveca]
          ]
          [Pro-Andine
            [Amuesha (Yanesha?)]
            [Amazonian
              [Marawa]
              [Waraiou]
            ]
            [Cutinana
              [Cushiehineri]
              [Cuniba] 
              [Cutinana]
            ]
            [Jurua-Purus
              [Casharari]
              [Catiana]
              [Inapari]
              [Apurina]
              [Manteneri]
              [Wainamari]
            ]
            [Montana
              [Piro (Yine)]
              [Pucapacuri] 
              [Puncuri] 
              [Sirimeri]
              [Campa
                [Asnaninca]
                [Asneninca]
                [Pajonal] 
                [Caquinte]
                [Machiguenga (Matsguenga)]
                [Nomatsiguenga]
              ] 
              [Harakmbet
                [Amarakaeri]
                [Huachipaeri]
          ] ] ]
          [Wapishanan
            [Wapishana]
          ]
          [Southern
            [Parana
              [Chane]
              [Guana]
              [Terena]
            ]
            [Bolivian
              [Baure]
              [Cashiniti]
              [Chiquito] 
              [Cozarini] 
              [Ignaciano (Mojeno Ignaciano)]
              [Trinitario]
          ] ]
          [Eastern
            [Palicur (Palikur)]
            [Xingu
              [Custenau]
              [Yawalapiti]
              [Mehinaku] 
              [Waura]
          ] ]
          [Northern
            [Island Carib]
            [Arua] 
            [Jaoi] 
            [Regigaro]
            [Caquetion
              [Achagua]
              [Caquetio]
            ]
            [Guayupean
              [Sae]
            ]
            [Orinoco
              [Guarequena] 
              [Bare] 
              [Guinao]
              [Mawacua]
              [Manipore]
            ]
            [Piapocan
              [Piapoco]
            ]
            [TA-Arawakan
              [Guajiro (Wayuu)]
              [Guanebucan] 
              [Arawak] 
              [Paraujano]
            ]
            [Rio Negro
              [Izaneni
                [Baniwa]
                [Curripaco]
                [Pacu] 
                [Cuati]
                [Mapanai]
                [Moriwene]
                [Izaneni]
              ]
              [Mantiparana
                [Cabiyari]
                [Matapi] 
                [Yucuna]
              ]
              [Wirina
                [Wirina]
                [Yabaana]
              ]
              [Tarianan
                [Itayaine]
                [Tariano]
              ]
              [Yapura A
                [Mariate]
                [Wainuma]
              ]
              [Yapura B
                [Cawishana]
                [Yumane] 
                [Passe]
                [Manao]
] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have not tried out myself but I am wondering if using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356922/121799) improves the situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error occurs.

Comment: Trisquel 8 seems to be based on Ubuntu 16.04, so you might have a pretty old version of TeX Live installed. Maybe installing TeX Live from the [website](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) would improve things, since I can compile your MWE without error, using LuaLaTeX (Version 1.07.0).

Answer (score 2):

the example runs without error in texlive 2018, the log ends

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 100796 strings out of 492580
 2042704 string characters out of 6129170
 1958899 words of memory out of 5000000
 104427 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 215i,9n,233p,1577b,53359s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on bb389.pdf (1 page, 63526 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

In particular note that the save stack size is still 80000 but the document stays within that at 53359s. So most likely you are using older versions of some macros that are less efficient in their use of the save stack. You could add `\listfiles` and show your package versions from the log.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running a very old TeX distribution, as I can only reproduce the issue with TeX Live 2015 or earlier.

On the other hand, if I run

```
save_size=1000000 /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/lualatex bigforest
```

in order to use `lualatex` from the 2015 distribution I have on my machine, the code compiles correctly. This is because `luatex` does dynamic memory allocation, so it can cope with big amounts of save stack memory, contrary to `pdftex`.

Try

```
save_size=1000000 lualatex bigforest
```

but it would be much better to upgrade your TeX distribution. See https://www.tug.org/texlive/ for instructions.

Comment: i have recent 64-bit `miktex` and cant compile with lua `2019-01-28 2.95`. error is similar as at op:    `! Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000].` and `Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 85529 strings out of 494300
 244514,1373583 words of node,token memory allocated 204422 words of node memory still in use:
   4591 hlist, 2 rule, 517 disc, 2 dir, 5492 glue, 668 kern, 6951 glyph, 11477 a
ttribute, 52 glue_spec, 11477 attribute_list, 1 temp, 27 if_stack, 1 write, 6882
 pdf_literal, 2 pdf_colorstack nodes` ...  how i can enlarge capacity?

Comment: @Zarko Not expert with MiKTeX, sorry.

Comment: that is pity. i will ask this as new question ...